# Scala: is a temporary var required to process a tuple return value?

Tags: scala, variables, queue, temporary

Consider the following sketch for using a loop to empty a queue in Scala:

```
var queue = immutable.Queue[T]( /* .. some content ..*/ )
while( !queue.isEmpty ) {
   val (record, tempQueue) = queue.dequeue
   queue = tempQueue
   doSomethingWith(record)
}
```

Is there any trick to avoid the temporary variable `tempQueue` and get Scala to assign the returned Queue value directly to the loop variable `queue`? Having to introduce the extra symbol is annoying, plus presumably there may be some superfluous copying (although this might get optimized away, not sure).

**Edit 1**: of course, as Ionut G. Stan points out, I can skip the pattern matching and take apart the returned pair myself, as in:

```
while( !queue.isEmpty ) {
   val pair = queue.dequeue
   queue = pair._2
   doSomethingWith(pair._1)
}
```

So I should refine the question as follows: is there any way to use the syntactic sugar of pattern matching to do this more elegantly? I was hoping for something like this, which unfortunately does not compile:

```
var queue = immutable.Queue[T]( /* .. some content ..*/ )
var record : A = _
while( !queue.isEmpty ) {
   (record, queue) = queue.dequeue
   doSomethingWith(record)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on keeping that structure (the `while` loop, etc.), I don't see how you can make it shorter, except perhaps:

```
var queue = immutable.Queue[T]( /* some content */ )
while( !queue.isEmpty ) queue.dequeue match {
  case (record, tempQueue) =>
    queue = queue.dequeue
    doSomethingWith(record)
}
```

Since you're using an immutable queue, however, the simplest equivalent code is probably:

```
for(record <- queue) {
  doSomethingWith(record)
}
```

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747783/scala-parallel-assignments-only-in-declarations) which confirms there is no way to assign to a pre-existing `var` with pattern-matching notation.

The [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), Section 4.1, is also clear: pattern-matching-style assignments expand into `val` definitions, i.e. they will bind a new identifier.

Comment: The problem with simplified examples for SO like mine above is that in reality you often want to do something more complicated, like not fully draining the queue (in which case the for loop won't work). The match you propose I guess is effectively equivalent to the code I had, and it still uses the temporary variable (I updated my question to give an example of what I was hoping for :-). I guess the answer may be that there is no way to do this, since it seems that I cannot extract pattern matching results into already-existing vars, only into newly defined vals.

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the related question that you kindly provided seems to be the (negative) answer to this question as well. I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're using a while loop with an immutable `Queue`.  Why not use a more functional approach (since you've got an immutable `Queue` anyway)?

You can define the function you want to run on each item in the `Queue` and then use a collections operation (map etc depending on the return you want) to apply it.

E.G.

```
  import scala.collection.immutable._

  val q = Queue[(Int,Int)]((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))

  def doSomethingWith(a:(Int,Int)) = {
    a swap
  }

  //returns a new Queue with each tuple's elements swapped
  q map doSomethingWith

  //returns unit (so only useful if doSomethingWith has a side effect)
  q foreach doSomethingWith
```

Comment: You are correct that this is a better approach for processing the entire queue. The problem with simplified examples like mine above is that in reality I want to do something more complicated, like not fully draining the queue (in which case map/clear won't work as easily). It may be an option, though, to partition the queue with a predicate and then fully drain and map one of the partitions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With immutable data structures, recursion is the FP way to do things.

```
def foo[T](queue: immutable.Queue[T]) {
  if (!queue.isEmpty) {
    val (record, remaining) = queue.dequeue
    doSomethingWith(record)
    foo(remaining)
  }
}
```

`foo(queue)` is basically the same as `queue foreach doSomethingWith`, which Brian Smith suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `_` prefixed members that are available up to [`Tuple22`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src/library/scala/Tuple22.scala):

```
scala> val a = (1,2)
a: (Int, Int) = (1,2)

scala> a._1
res0: Int = 1

scala> a._2
res1: Int = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, Ionut, this is of course correct, but I was hoping that there was a way to use the pattern matching to somehow overwrite the value of the already-existing variable `queue` while creating a new value for the `record`. I expanded the question and referenced your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pattern match, but it still introduces temp variables.

```
while( !queue.isEmpty ) {
  queue = queue.dequeue match {
    case (t: T, q: immutable.Queue[T]) =>      
      doSomethingWith(t)
      q
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little hack:

```
queue forall doSomethingWith
```

assuming that `doSomethingWith` is of type `T => Boolean`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the condition, you could maybe first filter the list, or use takeWhile and then map over the resulting set.
Something like

```
(queue takeWhile condition) foreach operation
```

or

```
(queue withFilter condition) foreach operation
```

This only works if the condition is a function of a single element.
You could also accumulate the part that you want with a fold (could look something like:)

```
(Nil /: queue)(<add element to accumulator if needed>) foreach operation
```